# A reference for $\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq X}\mu^2(n)= \frac{X}{\zeta(2)}+O(\sqrt{X}\exp(-c\sqrt{\log X}))$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

There is this result of counting the number of square-free numbers until $X$, which goes like this:

$$\sum_{n\leq X}\mu^2(n)= \frac{X}{\zeta(2)}+O(\sqrt{X}\exp(-c\sqrt{\log X})).$$

Could someone please point me to a reference which contains this result? I'd like to cite it and would prefer to refer the reader to a book or a paper. Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that Walfisz proved in 1963 that the error term is $$\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{x}\exp\left(-c\frac{(\log x)^{3/5}}{(\log\log x)^{1/5}}\right)\right)$$ which implies yours.

Comment: I would recommend Titchmarsh's _The theory of the Riemann zeta function_ as this formula is a direct corollary of many results from chapter 3 of that classic. (i.e. one can deduce it from Perron's formula using de la Vallée Puossin's zero-free region and the fact that $|\log\zeta(\sigma+it)|\le\log\log|t|+\mathcal O(1)$ as $|t|\to\infty$ in that region).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific reference mentioned by Tuvasbien is

Walfisz, Arnold. Weylsche Exponentialsummen in der neueren Zahlentheorie. *Mathematische Forschungsberichte, XV. VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften*, Berlin 1963.

The result quoted by Tuvasbien is Equation 27 on page 198. I don't know of an English reference for this result.

Comment: Thank you for hunting for the reference! :D